# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Document.querySelector with Google Fonts Link in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, google-fonts

After deploying a Next app to Vercel, I'm getting the following error code:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Document.querySelector: 'style[data-href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"]' is not a valid selector
```

[image]

Right now I'm calling this link through API on a whitelabel application in NextJS. I currently have a Layout component which wraps my application and it's called on _app.tsx.

This error doesn't occur on my local Next Server, only appears in production as you can see here:

https://www.wellaedu.com.br/

The code is wrapped on a Head tag as following:

```
      <Head>
        <title>{course?.title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={course?.short_description} />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link href={brand?.settings?.fonts?.font_link} rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
      </Head>
```

Has anybody faced this before? Any ideas of what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the `<link>` tag in a custom _document.js as in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-stylesheets-in-head-component).

```
// _document.js
import { Head } from 'next/document'

...

<Head>
  <link rel="icon" href={brand?.logo} />
  <link href={brand?.settings?.fonts?.font_link} rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
</Head>

...
```